# $(Q\to R)\wedge (R\to Q)$ converting to sentence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Well, I am following this video lecture (MOOC) and I came across this quiz where I have to convert $(Q\to R)\wedge (R\to Q)$  to sentence.

$Q$: "I will go to town"

$R$: "I have time"

My answer to $(Q\to R)\wedge (R\to Q)$  is

"I will go to town ONLY IF I have time AND I have time ONLY IF I will go to town".

Whereas, the professor teaching in video gave following answer:

"I will go to town ONLY IF I have time AND IF I have time I will go to town".

I don't get the answer given by professor because it changes the meaning of sentence after 'AND'.

NOTE: Further professor explain that this can be converted to equivalent "If and Only If", but my concern is not on equivalence. I understand that part.

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: @DavidRicherby "I don't get the answer given by professor because it changes the meaning of sentence after 'AND'."

Comment: Just ignore the professor.

Comment: @Umang.B That's a declarative statement. What's your _question_? Questions use words like "what" and "why" and end with question marks.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I searched further [here](https://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/logic/logic3.html) on net and found that Professor is correct. She used, "q if r" means r→q (2nd condition after AND) for "I will go to town IF I have time", but wrote it other way round.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I don't know I have to be that much specific. But by saying "I don't get the answer given by professor" with a specific reason: " it changes the meaning of sentence after 'AND" means I have confusion on the point where Professor represents her answer which in fact does not match my answer (or what I understand as standard translation of 'condition' statements given in book like [Rosen](https://www.amazon.in/Discrete-Mathematics-Its-Applications-SIE/dp/0070681880/ref=pd_sbs_14_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=YW98G26XSXTKSNPWA0V8)

Answer (score 1):

Your answer and the professor's answer are both correct.  Other ways to say $p$ implies $q$ are: "if $p$ then $q$" and "$p$ only if $q$".  You can replace "only if" by "implies".

Thus, "I have time ONLY IF I will go to town" and "IF I have time I will go to town" both say the same thing - "I have time implies I will go to town".

Comment: Except this is not true, for the simple reason that P implies Q means that Q is satisfied whenever P is satisfied, but not necessarily that Q is ONLY ever satisfied if P is satisfied (Q might be satisfied on its own, the implication of P on Q does not tell us that). The only-if part (iff) in the question comes from the fact that it is a conjuction.

Comment: @DeBunkeD The terminology I'm using is actually quite standard. You can check out the book "Discrete Mathematics and its Applications" by Kenneth Rosen. Chapter 1 says that "p implies q" and "p only if q" mean exactly the same thing. Perhaps other people use different terminology.

Comment: @DeBunkeD Consider the statement "If I live in Chennai, then I live in India".  It's of the form "if p, then q".  Thus, p is true forces q to be true.  p can be true only if q is true in the first place (for if q is false, then p would be false), and so we can say "p only if q".

Comment: I've just realized I misread your answer yesterday. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

### There are multiple ways of understanding **IMPLICATIONS** statements.
In brief,

**x**$\implies$ **y** can be written as

- **if** x **then** y
- y **if** x
- x **only if** y
- x **is sufficient for** y
- y **is necessary for** x
- x **implies** y       ​
- y **is implied by** x       ​
- ~y **implies** ~x
- y **provided** x       ​       ​
- y **follows from** x       ​
- y **whenever** x       ​
- y **without** x **is possible**       ​
- x **without** y **is not possible**       ​

Now, many of these might sound *confusing* in one go, but with *examples* and *repetition of thought process*, they become clear. One more thing, that while practicing question, we should often ignore our understanding of nature and the thought process if it is possible or not. Moreover, this might sound confusing because of our understanding of *English Language* and more specifically *Tenses*. Translating these in mother tongue often helps!

### Now, **the question**.

$Q :$ "I will go to town"
$R :$ "I have time"

Now, $Q \implies R$ using **only if** will give :

> I will go to town **ONLY IF** I have time.

Now, $R \implies Q$ using **if-then** will give :

> **IF** I have time **THEN** I will go to town.

Thus, if your professor has used word **"THEN"** then his solution is correct. Otherwise, not being so strict on language, if we even miss **THEN**, and had a pause (comma) instead of **THEN**, *[then]* the meaning doesn't change. Although, correct solution among multiple correct solutions is :

> *I will go to town **ONLY IF** I have time* **AND** ***IF** I have time **THEN** I will go to town.*

### REFERENCES

Page 335-336 of [this](https://ncert.nic.in/textbook.php?kemh1=14-16) Textbook *(Page 15-16 of PDF)* **and** Page 251-252 of [this](https://ncert.nic.in/pdf/publication/exemplarproblem/classXI/mathematics/keep214.pdf) Textbook *(Page 6-7 of PDF)*.

Answer (score 0):

IMO both you and the teacher read in a contrived way. I would say "I go to town implies that I have time and I have time implies that I go to town".

Note that as this is formal logics, no causation should be considered. (I am not going to town *because* I have time nor conversely; it is just two events that will simultaneously occur or not occur.)

Answer (score -1):

Note that

$$Q\iff R\equiv(Q\to R)\wedge (R\to Q).$$
Hence your professor and you say same thing.